# How can I load my css file on my express.static

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

How can I load my css file on my express.static
I have tried many ways to put my style on my html file using express, I would like to know how to put imgs, js and others. Basically to make my website more dynamic.
I have try many solution, but I cant find the right one

```
const express=require('express')
const app=express()


app.use(express.static(__dirname));

getId=(req,res)=>{
       const id=req.params.id*1
        res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);
        
}

app.get('/hibiscos/:id',getId)

const port =8000;


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor funcionando na porta ${port}...`);
  //console.log(`${__dirname}`);
});
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUaPr1lz_WY, this video may have your answer. The 7 minute mark is the step you are currently at.

Answer (score 0):

You have added `app.use(express.static(__dirname));` in your code. So, all files in the current directory* can be accessed by `/`. You only have to put those .css, .js, and other static files in the current directory*. After that you can access them by getting `/`. For example: `/style.css`, `/image.png`, `/script.js`, etc.

---

*Current directory means the value of `__dirname`